# how to store this info in qt? arraylist-ish ?

Tags: arrays, qt, qlist, qmap, qvector

new bee here.
I am sorry if there are similar questions but i just dont even know how to ask it properly. the thing is, i have to do some project for the uni and i am stuck now.
i am getting info through udp and need to store the yield info to pass in to objects(car coordinates)
i have to do it for 20 objects therefore it is much more complicated.
i have this code and it should be working as my prof. told me but i have to figure out how, on my own, to store it.
tried QList and QMap but i couldnt figure out how it is possible to have

anArray[num].posX=somenumber;

so i have to store coordinates for each car as car1.x, car1.y, car1z then in the loop count increases; car2.x and so on.

i dont know if my question or what i wanted to ask is clear enough but please bear with me

```
while(mSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
        QByteArray datagram;
        QHostAddress crrAddress;
        quint16 crrPort;
        datagram.resize( int(mSocket->pendingDatagramSize()) );
        mSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &crrAddress, &crrPort);             
        double* resultList = new double[(datagram.size() / int(sizeof(double))) ];

        memcpy(&resultList[0], datagram.data(), size_t(datagram.size()));

        for(quint16 count = 0; (count) < mVehicleCount; count++) {
            mVehicleMap[mArrayOffset + count].ID = int16_t(resultList[7 + 11 * count]);
            mVehicleMap[mArrayOffset + count].pose.position.x = resultList[(1 + 11 * count)];
            mVehicleMap[mArrayOffset + count].pose.position.y = resultList[(2 + 11 * count)];
            mVehicleMap[mArrayOffset + count].pose.position.z = resultList[(3 + 11 * count)];
            mVehicleMap[mArrayOffset + count].pose.orientation.x = resultList[(6 + 11 * count)];
        }
        delete[] resultList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QList` or `QVector` class for your goal (Qt documentation: [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html), [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html)).

Simple example for `QVector`:

```
    struct Vehicle
    {
        qint16 ID_;
        double position_x_;
        double position_y_;
        double position_z_;
        double orintation_x_;
    };

    ...

    QVector<Vehicle> vehicles(maxVehicleCount);  // maxVehicalCount - you variable

    ...

    while(mSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
            QByteArray datagram;
            QHostAddress crrAddress;
            quint16 crrPort;
            datagram.resize( int(mSocket->pendingDatagramSize()) );
            mSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &crrAddress, &crrPort);             
            double* resultList = new double[(datagram.size() / int(sizeof(double))) ];

            memcpy(&resultList[0], datagram.data(), size_t(datagram.size()));

            for(quint16 count = 0; (count) < mVehicleCount; count++) {
                vehicles[mArrayOffset + count].ID_ = qint16(resultList[7 + 11 * count]);
                vehicles[mArrayOffset + count].position_x_ = resultList[(1 + 11 * count)];
                vehicles[mArrayOffset + count].position_y_ = resultList[(2 + 11 * count)];
                vehicles[mArrayOffset + count].position_z_ = resultList[(3 + 11 * count)];
                vehicles[mArrayOffset + count].orintation_x_ = resultList[(6 + 11 * count)];
            }
            delete[] resultList;
    }
```

Also you can use `QMap` class (Qt doucmentation: [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html)):

```
    struct Vehicle
    {
        qint16 ID_;
        double position_x_;
        double position_y_;
        double position_z_;
        double orintation_x_;
    };

    ...

    QMap<qint16, Vehicle*> vehicleMap;

    ...

    while(true/*mSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()*/){
            QByteArray datagram;
            QHostAddress crrAddress;
            quint16 crrPort;
            datagram.resize( int(mSocket->pendingDatagramSize()) );
            mSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &crrAddress, &crrPort);             
            double* resultList = new double[(datagram.size() / int(sizeof(double))) ];

            memcpy(&resultList[0], datagram.data(), size_t(datagram.size()));

            for(quint16 count = 0; (count) < mVehicleCount; count++) {
                Vehicle* vehicle = new Vehicle();
                vehicle.ID_ = qint16(resultList[7 + 11 * count]);
                vehicle.position_x_ = resultList[(1 + 11 * count)];
                vehicle.position_y_ = resultList[(2 + 11 * count)];
                vehicle.position_z_ = resultList[(3 + 11 * count)];
                vehicle.orintation_x_ = resultList[(6 + 11 * count)];
                vehicleMap.insert(vehicle.ID_, vehicle);
            }
            delete[] resultList;
    }
```

Comment: @AhmetBat please consider accepting the answer if it helped you

Comment: sorry, didnt really know it was necessary